# Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IAzureADProps'

Tags: react-native, react-aad-msal

We are using react-aad-msal for AD authentication. After upgrading my application to  react 18, I am getting below error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ children: ({ login, authenticationState, error, accountInfo, }: IAzureADFunctionProps) => void | Element; provider: MsalAuthProvider; reduxStore: Store<{ appState: AppState; ... 10 more ...; webhooks: InitialState; }, AnyAction> & { ...; }; forceLogin: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IAzureADProps'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IAzureADProps'.
    65 |       <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    66 |         <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  > 67 |           <AzureAD provider={authProvider} reduxStore={store} forceLogin={true}>
       |            ^^^^^^^
    68 |             {({
    69 |               login,
    70 |               authenticationState,
```

I am trying to upgrade my existing application 16 to 18.

Comment: Looks like you guys are encountering a TypeScript build error since you are upgrading React 16 to 18.  Ensure that you're using the latest version of TypeScript and the library in question. Sometimes, type issues are resolved in newer versions of the libraries, or there might be breaking changes that you need to accommodate in your code.

Comment: We are using all latest version of typescript and package of react-aad-msal for AzureAD